# Combine React-mentions component and Material-UI(MUI) TextField?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to incorporate React-mentions in to the comment section for the application I'm building. As of now the styling and functionality is all already in place with MUI-components. It looks and works in a way that I like. So what I'm wondering if there is some way to combine the two different library components?

Is this possible at all?

I've tried to make some sort of own custom component, but I'm using typescript and can't get past some of the errors regarding types and interfaces. Here's an example of how I think a custom component maybe could look:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MentionsInput, Mention } from 'react-mentions';
import TextField, { TextFieldProps } from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

interface MentionTextFieldProps extends TextFieldProps {
  mentionsProps: {
    value: string;
    onChange: (value: string) => void;
  };
}

const MentionTextField: React.FC<MentionTextFieldProps> = ({
  mentionsProps,
  ...textFieldProps
}) => {
  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    mentionsProps.onChange(value);
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      {...textFieldProps}
      onChange={handleChange}
      multiline
      inputProps={{
        style: { lineHeight: '1.5', whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' },
      }}
    >
      <MentionsInput value={mentionsProps.value} onChange={mentionsProps.onChange}>
        <Mention
          trigger="@"
          data={[]}
        />
      </MentionsInput>
    </TextField>
  );
};

export default MentionTextField;
```

In a perfect world this is how I would like to solve it:

```
       <TextField
       id="comment-field"
       onChange={handleChange}
       onKeyUp={handleKeyUp}
       name="comment"
       label="Leave a comment"
       multiline
       fullWidth
       minRows={2}
       placeholder="..."
       helperText={validationError ? errors[validationError] : ""}
       error={!!validationError}
       disabled={conditionsThatMakeTheTextFieldDisabled}
       sx={(theme) => ({
         backgroundColor:
           context === "someSortOfContext"
             ? theme.palette.highlight.main
             : theme.palette.background.paper,
       })}
       color={context === "internal" ? "warning" : "primary"}
     >
        <MentionsInput
         value={commentValue}
         singleLine={false}
         onChange={(e) => setCommentValue(e.target.value)}
       >
         <Mention trigger="@" data={realUsers} />
       </MentionsInput>
     </TextField>
```

This doesn't really throw any errors, it's just that the mentions-component doesn't work at all.

This on it's own work but I would have to replace the Textfield that I already have in place:

```
           <MentionsInput
            value={commentValue}
            singleLine={false}
            onChange={(e) => setCommentValue(e.target.value)}
          >
            <Mention trigger="@" data={realUsers} />
          </MentionsInput>
```